# Mongoose always returns an empty array in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to pull all the `products` of of the `products` collection on MongoDB Atlas. All I get in return are empty arrays.

I have a proper connection to the database.

I am unsure about the model and how I am using Mongoose.

Here is my connection... `connectDb.js`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const connection = {};

async function connectDb() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    console.log("Connection in progress");
    return;
  }
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_SRV, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log("DB Connected");
  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
}

export default connectDb;
```

Here is my schema... `./models/Product.js`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import shortid from "shortid";

const { String, Number } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  sku: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    default: shortid.generate(),
  },
  mediaUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

// Check for an existing `models.Product` ... then run the product schema
export default mongoose.models.Product ||
  mongoose.model("products", ProductSchema);
```

Here is my query ... `./api/products.js`

```
import Product from "../../models/Product";
import connectDb from "../../utils/connectDb";

connectDb();

export default async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find({});
  console.log(`products are ... ${products}`);
  res.status(200).json(products);
};
```

Here is my database

[image: name of collection]

[image: what the data looks like]

Here is the results in the console...

[image]

According to Mongoose Documentation if `db.connections[0].readyState}` returns 1... it means connected [Connection Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-readyState)

[image]

Comment: I read the other forums and made the following changes to ensure no repeats...          1) I updated mongoose to latest       2) I used `.find({})` and NOT `.find()`

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right database?

Comment: Which part of the application are you running the query from (I see a portion of the query definition in the post)?

Comment: I know that the connection is good because `console.log("DB Connected");` successfully runs

Comment: @prasad.... This is a client Next.js app running locally on my computer making MongoDB calls to MongoDB Atlas. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Just because "DB Connected" is logged to the console doesn't mean you have a connection.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I added a `console.log()` for the `connections.readyState` proving that I am connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `env` var `MONGO_SRV`. Make sure that your connection URL is with the relevant DB.

Comment: This was it... MongoDB Atlas gives you a connection to a default database called myFirstDatabase.... you need to change it.... ``"mongodb+srv://username:password@dataname.asdf.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`